# OpenLDAP error while adding an ACL

Tags: linux, ldap

I'm trying to add an ACL to my DIT and I get the following:

```
Enter LDAP Password: 
modifying entry "olcDatabase={0}bdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
        matched DN: cn=config
```

This is the content of the acl.ldif file:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword by dn="cn=Manager,dc=site,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=Manager,dc=site,dc=com" write by * read
```

Comment: And what `ldap` command are you using. Looks like you're not binding the `cn=config` database.